# How to create a scrolling background image with css/jquery/html

Tags: css, html, web

I am hoping to find out how people make the background of the section/div of their website move when scrolled.

An example of what I am talking about is like this:

http://dsathemes.com/html/xlander/contact/index.html#skills

I am not quite sure how to explain it, sorry. I have tried `background-position: 50%;`, `background-attachment: fixed;`. But I have still had no luck :(

Thanks in advance,

Kieron

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a [Parallax effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling), where a background moves at a set rate in relation to how far the user scrolls. You could achieve this either with [Javascript](http://andyshora.com/parallax.html) or with a [CSS-only solution](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's parallax effect as said [Timmah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594373/timmah), you can achieve this trought CSS & jQuery have a look [here](http://andyshora.com/parallax.html)